# Replace app label with filter button

Tags: android, xml

I want to add a filter button in place of my app's label in the action bar.

So where 'APP NAME' is I want a 'Filter' button and onClick() will start another action. I would post an image but I don't have enough reputation points. -_-

I've been looking at various solutions but I think I may be over complicating an easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`setCustomView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setCustomView%28int%29) method of `ActionBar` to achieve what you want.